# JRadioButton cannot be cast to JButton in EventListener

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener, event-listener, jradiobutton

I'm having an issue where I get a lot of red lines in my interactions output when I click a `JRadioButton` in my code. The program is asking the user to select one of four answers to a question "What is your favourite fruit?" Here is an extract from the code:

```
   //constructor
    public Form(){

    EventListener listener = new EventListener();

    private class EventListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    if ((JButton)e.getSource() == fruitButton) {

    selectA = new JRadioButton("Apples");
    selectA.addActionListener(listener);
    selectB = new JRadioButton("Bananas");
    selectB.addActionListener(listener);
    selectC = new JRadioButton("Cherries");
    selectC.addActionListener(listener);
    selectD = new JRadioButton("Other");
    selectD.addActionListener(listener);

    if ((JButton)e.getSource() == quitButton) {
    System.exit(1);
    }

    if (selectAButton.isSelected() || selectBButton.isSelected() || selectCButton.isSelected() || selectDButton.isSelected()) {
    southPanel.add(submitButton);
    }
}}
```

However, when I run the code whenever I click one of the select `JRadioButtons` I get lots of red lines in the interactions output, starting with:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JRadioButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JButton`

I have `JButtons` in the same Event Listener (there's a quit button for example) but no matter what I do I cannot seem to get the submit button to add at the bottom once a radio button has been selected. Please help!

Comment: provide the complete code with the `button` declaration

Comment: You are casting the source of your event unconditionally to a JButton. This leads to a ClassCastException when the source is a JRadioButton. You have to check with instanceof first what you get and then cast.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the event source is indeed a JButton before you cast it:

```
    if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton  && (JButton)e.getSource() == quitButton) {

            System.exit(1);
    }
```